# Why has my Ubuntu 17.10 become Ubuntu 17.10 Kylin?

Tags: 17.10, kylin

I have been using Ubuntu 17.10 right after its release. It has been updating and upgrading since then automatically.

Today (11 Dec. 2017) I suddenly noticed that, the trash icon in my desktop is labeled in Chinese! Then I went to the 'About' section from Settings, and it says my system is now Ubuntu 17.10 Kylin!

[image]

Why and how did this thing happen? And how can I roll back to original Ubuntu?

Comment: Did you install a screen-saver maybe?

Comment: @Videonauth yes! Is this the reason? Should I remove it?

Comment: Depending on which screen-saver you installed yes that alone can be the reason. Not sure how deep it goes into the system tho. I guess your Firefox is as well locked to 123.sugou.com ? Can you please [edit] your question and include what you did before this happened in therms of installing.

Comment: Sure. I will try to list all the (probable) suspicious actions taken in last few days.

Comment: Reading through `/var/log/apt/history.log` might help you with this task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for that, Did you installed ukui-screensaver or other kylin packages? if so, you can remove all the stuff by:

```
$ sudo apt purge ukui-screensaver ubuntukylin-default-settings
```

to roll back to original Ubuntu.